# Python leave() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, class, methods, python-3.x, self

Ok so my problem is that when calling a method inside of my class from outside(top level), it takes the self parameter as if it would be an argument that it wants a value for, my class:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=5000):
        try:
            self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_socket.connect((host, port))
            info.set("Connected...")
            self.boool = True
            self.gotten = ""
            self.data = ""
            b1.config(state=NORMAL)
            b2.config(state=NORMAL)
            textEntry.config(state=NORMAL)
            time.sleep(1)
            threading.Timer(1.0, self.listen).start()
        except socket.error as error:
            self.boool = False
            info.set(str(error)[14:])
        except:
            self.boool = False
            info.set("An unknown error occured")


    def leave(self):
        self.boool = False
        self.server_socket.close()
        b1.config(state=DISABLED)
        b2.config(state=DISABLED)
        textEntry.config(state=DISABLED)

    def listen(self):       
        while self.boool == True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.data = self.server_socket.recv(512)
            if self.data == bytes('quit', 'UTF-8'):
                self.leave()
                print("Server has left the chat")
            elif self.data != self.gotten:
                v.set("Server: %s\n%s" % (self.data, v.get()))
                self.gotten = self.data


    def send(self, message=''):
        self.data.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
        v.set("Client: %s\n%s" % (message, v.get()))
```

And my tkinter buttons that calls the Client class and one that calls the method leave():

```
b2 = Button(root, text="Leave", width=8, state=DISABLED, command=Client.leave)
b2.grid(row=0, column=3)
Button(root, text="Connect", width=8, command=Client).grid(row=0, column=4)
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\chatClient2.py", line 68, in <module>
b2 = Button(root, text="Leave", width=8, state=DISABLED, command=Client.leave)
TypeError: leave() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: There is and indent. after 'class Client:', just so you know.

Comment: Could you show the error you get when you replace `Client.leave` with `Client().leave`? I believe that should give you a bound method and therefore work...

Comment: You're absolutely correct, that does work so now my problem would be that: '''b2 = Button(root, text="Leave", width=8, state=DISABLED, command=Client().leave)''', calls the Client class upon start up which is not intended the class is supposed to be called when clicking the connect button only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client instance is supposed to be created when the user presses the "Connect" button, so let it call a method `GUI.connect`, which creates `self.client=Client()`.

Then use a second method `GUI.leave`, which when called, delegates to `self.client.leave()`:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
    def setup_buttons(self):
        self.b1 = ...
        self.b2 = Button(root, text = "Leave", width = 8, state = DISABLED, command = self.leave)
        b2.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        Button(root, text = "Connect", width = 8, command = self.connect).grid(row = 0, column = 4)
    def connect(self):
        self.b1.config(state = NORMAL)
        self.b2.config(state = NORMAL)
        self.client = Client()
    def leave(self):
        if self.client:
            self.b1.config(state = DISABLED)
            self.b2.config(state = DISABLED)
            self.client.leave()
```

Comment: That is very true, although i've tryed using Client().leave as well and it generates the same error :(

Comment: Oops.. you are using Python3. The concept of unbound method has been removed in Python3. Editing answer...

Comment: When initiating GUI(), that in turn calling setup_buttons(), for some reason, the class Client() is called just by having command=Client().leave, when changing it to command=Client.leave: it isn't.

Comment: Right. `Client()` calls `Client.__init__(...)`, But `Client.leave` does not. Try using `command = self.leave` and `command = self.connect` instead.

Comment: Thanks again, but now b2 isn't a global variable, which means that when calling it at Client.__init__(), it isn't recognized. I know you can solve this easily by setting global b2 or something similiar, but that is not something I like to do.

Comment: Ok, I would try to separate the `GUI` from the `Client` as much as possible. (That is, don't make the `Client` depend on `GUI`, in case you want to build a different GUI on top of the same `Client` one day.). So, I would move the `b1`, `b2` stuff out of `Client` and back into `GUI`. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.